# Make tags on Select editable

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd

I'm using `Select` component from `antd` Design in my React app with `Tag` mode, and I want the tags inside that `Select` to be editable when the user double click on it

Any idea how can I do that?

Here is the code so far:

```
<Select
     showSearch={false}
     mode="tags"
     onChange={handleChange}
     tokenSeparators={[',']}
     value={Tags}
 >
     {children}
</Select>
```

Comment: What's the point of making them editable? They can press backspace and type a new tag

Comment: it came as a requirement, they want the user to be able to fix any mistake on the tag rather than delete it and write again

Comment: Hah client requirements, never makes sense XD

Answer (score 0):

Check out React Synthetic Event : https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events

```
<option onDoubleClick={yourFunctionForDoubleClick} value={option.value}>{option.label}</option>

yourFunctionForDoubleClick =(event)=> { your logic here, then setState({yourState: event.target.value})}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this double click will be for the option itself not the tag! "selected option"